# Codeigniter Pagination repeated content with Page numbers

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a blog with a pagination. Works everything fine except the items displayed are repeated.
The items are displayed randomly repeated on the other pages. For example, on the second page it displays an item that is already on the first page.

So, I have this function in my controller.

```
public function index() {

    //Pagination
    $config['per_page']  = 4;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['base_url']  = base_url().'blog/index';
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $num_rows = $this->db->get('posts');

    foreach ($num_rows->result() as $row) {}
    $num_rows = $num_rows->num_rows();

    $num_rows          = $num_rows;
    $config['total_rows']    = $num_rows;
    //Primeira página
    $config['first_link']    = '<span style="font-weight: bold;color: rgb(225,2,38);"><<</span>';
    //Última página
    $config['last_link']     = '<span style="font-weight: bold;color: rgb(225,2,38);">>></span>';
    //Página anterior
    $config['prev_link']     = '<button type="select" class="selectarrowleft" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
    //Próxima página
    $config['next_link']     = '<button type="select" class="selectarrowright" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
    //Páginas disponiveis
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<div>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    //Página corrente
    $config['cur_tag_open']  = '<div id="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $data['blog'] = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));

    $this->load->view('frontend/template/header');
    $this->load->view('frontend/template/nav_bar');
    $this->load->view('frontend/pages/blog', $data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/template/footer');
  }
```

And this is the code on the view:

```
<?php
foreach ($blog->result() as $row) {
// The code for showing my blog articles
}
// pagination links
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
```

If I set this false:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;
```

The blog articles are displayed correctly without repeated articles. But I really want to have the correct page numbers. What can I do? I've seen so many questions similar to this but I wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: Is this correct? foreach ($num_rows->result() as $row) {}
    $num_rows = $num_rows->num_rows();

    $num_rows          = $num_rows;

Comment: are the items repeated on the same page? next page? are the REPEATED(along with new items) or is it that the same items keep displaying again? you are not providing an offset properly.

Comment: try $num_rows = $num_rows->num_rows(); above the foreach() loop with different variable name like $totalRow = $num_rows->num_rows(); AND $config['total_rows']    = $totalRow;

Comment: here $num_rows varibale may colliding with total number of rows with mysql results

Comment: The items are displayed randomly repeated on the other pages. For example, on the second page it displays an item that is already on the first page.

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan That solution did nothing sadly. I guess it's not coliding.

Comment: why you name all the variables like **$num_rows**?, I guest you put this like an example, that that is not the real name of your variables, if that are the names, see if the variable do not change its **value**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is `$this->uri->segment(4);`, you should set it `$this->uri->segment(3);`, because if you set segment 4, you will get nothing unless you want to get something more in URL, or:

```
public function index($page = 1) { //Default is 1
```

The `$page` number will do the same thing just like you get uri segment. Then you set your `$start` variable in `limit($limit, $start)` method.

```
$start = ($page - 1) * $config['per_page'];
$data['blog'] = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'], $start);
```